# Nullable Types and properties with INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, vb.net, nullable, inotifypropertychanged

It seems like overkill to set the value of a nullable type and implement iNotifyPropertyChanged. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
        Private _WorkPhone As Long?
    Public Property [WorkPhone]() As Long?
        Get
            Return _WorkPhone
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Long?)
            If value.HasValue = False Then
                If _WorkPhone.HasValue = True Then
                    MyBase.RaisePropertyChanging("WorkPhone")
                    _WorkPhone = Nothing
                    MyBase.MarkDirty()
                    MyBase.RaisePropertyChanged("WorkPhone")
                End If
            Else
                If _WorkPhone.HasValue Then
                    If _WorkPhone.Value <> value.Value Then
                        MyBase.RaisePropertyChanging("WorkPhone")
                        _WorkPhone = value
                        MyBase.MarkDirty()
                        MyBase.RaisePropertyChanged("WorkPhone")
                    End If
                Else
                    MyBase.RaisePropertyChanging("WorkPhone")
                    _WorkPhone = value
                    MyBase.MarkDirty()
                End If
                MyBase.RaisePropertyChanged("WorkPhone")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
```

I tried using simple code, but my breakpoint on **MyBase.RaisePropertyChanging("WorkPhone")** is never hit, and the value never changes.

```
    If _WorkPhone <> value Then
    MyBase.RaisePropertyChanging("WorkPhone")
    _WorkPhone = value
    MyBase.MarkDirty()
    MyBase.RaisePropertyChanged("WorkPhone")
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for all the complicated logic. If `x` and `y` are both nullables with the same underlying type then `x` equals `y` if and only if

1. `x.HasValue` is `true`
2. `y.HasValue` is `true`
3. `x.Value` equals `y.Value`

or

1. `x.HasValue` is `false`
2. `y.HasValue` is `false`

In neither of these cases would we want to raise a property changed notification and thus a simple test for non-equality will suffice. Thus:

```
Private _WorkPhone As Long?
    Public Property [WorkPhone]() As Long?
        Get
            Return _WorkPhone
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Long?)
            If Not _workPhone.Equals(value)
                MyBase.RaisePropertyChanging("WorkPhone")
                _WorkPhone = value
                MyBase.MarkDirty()
                MyBase.RaisePropertyChanged("WorkPhone")
            EndIf
        End Set
    End Property
```

Note that we ned to use `Not Nullable(Of T).Equals` instead of `<>` as the latter evaluates to `Nothing` if one if its operands is `Nothing`.

Comment: This is exactly the code I was using, but in the postback from asp.net, it was not getting to the first mybase.raisepropertychanging call. It was not setting the value, hence the complicated logic.

Comment: @Rick Ratayczak: What were the values of `_workPhone` and `value` in that case? Unless we're both overlooking something subtle, the above should be correct.

Comment: _workphone.hasvalue = false, and value.hasvalue = true
I am passing in a phone number, to a property without.

Comment: Okay, use `Not _workPhone.Equals(value)` instead of `_workPhone <> value` and you should be fine. The operator `<>` evalues to `Nothing` when one of its operands is `Nothing`; this is why you need to use `Object.Equals` which is overrode for `Nullable(Of T)` to behave correctly.

Comment: Ok, I officially love you, but in a bromance kinda way. lol Thanks for this fix!

Comment: Thank you for adding a new word to my vocabulary. I had never heard the word "bromance" before.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside...I notice you are using a LONG to store the work phone number.  Even unsigned this will fail above areacode 429 in the U.S. You might consider DOUBLE or STRING

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the feedback. This is coming from Entity Framework, so I'll change the DB.